# How to skip a print in java "if"

Tags: java, if-statement

Basically what I want to do is to print a plural word when "HundredBill" is greater than 1, to print a singular word when "HundredBill" is equal 1, and to print nothing but continue with the printing for "FiftyBill". For example: when I enter 150, the output will be 1 Hundred. When I enter 50, the output will be 1 Fifty(it skips showing 0 Hundred.)

Thanks for the help!

```
if (HundredBill > 1) {
  System.out.printf("%d Hundreds\n", Hundred);
}else if(HundredBill == 1){
  System.out.printf("%d Hundred\n", Hundred);
}else if(HundredBill == 0){
}
if (FiftyBill = 1) {
  System.out.printf("%d Fifty\n", Fifty);
```

Comment: Didn't get your question

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question, your pseudo-code does what you asked for...

Comment: Didn't get it either... Also `if (FiftyBill = 1)` is probably wrong.

Comment: What is the current output? You should also give the full code because here we can't see how `HundredBill`, `Hundled`, `FiftyBill` and `Fifty` are computed. Also, following java conventions you should start your variable names with a lowercase letter.

Comment: if you enter 50 it should give **1 Fifty and 0 Hundred**? Didn't get you.. and your final **if** doesn't have closing brace

Comment: When you entre 150, does it print text on 2 lines? If not, you may have a problem parsing the value.

Comment: How is `HundredBill` calculated? Is it something like `HundredBill = someValue/100`?

Comment: Some do it like `System.out.printf("%d hundred%s, Hundred, Hundred > 1 ? "s" : "");`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    int price=150;
    int hundred=price/100;
    if(hundred==1 || hundred==0){
          System.out.println(hundred+" hundread");
    }else{  
         System.out.println( hundred+" hundreads");
    }
    price%=100;
    int fifty=price/50;
    if(fifty==1||fifty==0){
            System.out.println(fifty+" fifty");
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question. The only part I got from your question.

> when I enter 150, the output will be 1 Hundred. When I enter 50, the
>   output will be 1 Fifty

You can try something like this

```
int val = 150;
int hundreds = val / 100;
int fifties;
if (hundreds == 0) {
   fifties = val / 50;
    System.out.println("fifties "+fifties);
}else {
  System.out.println("Hundreds "+hundreds);
}
```

Comments for your code.

```
if (FiftyBill = 1) // here FiftyBill = 1 is not a boolean you will get
                   // compile errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for breaking down the input into different amounts, the best way to do that is to use a recursive code just like this:

```
private static void toWord(int i) {

    if(i >= 100){
        System.out.println( (i/100) + " Hundred(s)");
        toWord(i%100);
    }
    else if(i >= 50){
        System.out.println( (i/50) + " Fifty(ies)");
        toWord(i%50);
    }
}
```

then you access that method by:

```
toWord(570);//any input number
```

if you want to extend it to support thousands just add in the method:

```
if(i >= 1000){        
        System.out.println((i/1000) + " Thousand(s)");
        toWord(i%1000);
    }// and change the first if into "else if"
```

That should solve your problem :)